# Why isn't d3 text appearing on bar chart when using new dataset?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, bar-chart

I've got two bar charts written with almost identical d3 code.

When you click on "After Transfers", the bars move and the white numbers change.

In this CodePen of vertical bars, it works. [VERTICAL BAR CHART](http://codepen.io/silentkrange/pen/jcAam)

In this CodePen of horizontal bars, it doesn't work. [HORIZONTAL BAR CHART](http://codepen.io/silentkrange/pen/GEDlr)

Can anyone help me debug? I'm stumped...

```
CODE FOR VERTICAL BAR LABELS
var drawNewlabels = svg.selectAll("text")
.data(dataset)
.text(function(d) {return d;})
.attr('opacity',0)
.attr("x", function(d, i) {return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;})
.attr("y", function(d) {return h - yScale(d) + 14;});
drawNewlabels.transition().delay(1000).duration(500)
.attr('opacity',1)

CODE FOR HORIZONTAL BAR LABELS
var drawNewlabels = svg.selectAll("text")
.data(dataset)
.text(function(d) {return d;})
.attr('opacity',0)
.attr("y", function(d,i) {return yScale(i) + (yScale.rangeBand() / 2) + 4;})
.attr("x", function(d) {return xScale(d) + 14;})
drawNewlabels.transition().delay(1000).duration(500)
.attr('opacity',1)
```

Comment: Hi was the below answer what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The mouse event was causing an error here is a working code pen http://codepen.io/leighquince/pen/JAFmt

There is also no need to redelare them as the listeners are still on the rectangles from when you first declare them.

Oh also I removed the -512 from

```
  .attr("x", function(d) {return xScale(d) -512;})
```

and replaced it with

```
  .attr("x", function(d) {return xScale(d) -20;})
```

so that the text appears at the end of the bar